# Does indeterministic event imply the violation of causality?

Tags: causality, determinism

In many cases, an indeterministic event were accompanied by the violation of causality in certain theory.

However, does indeterminstic event in general imply the violation of causality in classical (mechanics) logic or quantum (mechanics) logic?

Answer (score 1):

Indeterministic events don't violate anything. Every event is indeterministic, there is no determinism at all in reality.

Indeterminism is nothing but the absence of determinism. It does not mean the absence or violation of causality. In reality, causes never determine their effects with absolute accuracy. Causes only determine the probability distribution where the effect lands.

In the quantum scale the effects may vary widely, but in the classical scale billions of quantum events will cancel out each other yielding a quasi-deterministic very close to average outcome.